# Getting error : Call to undefined function dio_fcntl() for OBD gateway

Tags: php, error-handling, obd-ii

Here I want to implement OBD gateway in php v7.0. For that i had used https://github.com/mdlayher/obd library. In this library there is one function `dio_fcntl()` used and i am getting error and unable to use it.  I also enable php_dio extension from php.ini file. Still i got fatal error like as below.

> "Fatal error: Call to undefined function serial\dio_fcntl()".

[image: error]

```
public function __construct($device, $flags = 02)
    {
        // Attempt to set device...
        if (!$this->set_device($device))
        {
            throw new \Exception("Unable to set device for serial connection");
        }

        // Check if Direct IO extension installed
        if (!function_exists("dio_open"))
        {
            throw new \Exception("PHP Direct IO is not installed, cannot open serial connection!");
        }

        // $device : /dev/pts/ELM327
        // Create direct IO file handle with specified flags
        $this->serial = dio_open("C:/wamp/www/obd-master/".$device, $flags);

        // Set synchronous IO
        dio_fcntl($this->serial, F_SETFL, O_SYNC);

        // Set options default
        $options = array(
            "baud" => self::DEFAULT_BAUD,
            "bits" => self::DEFAULT_BITS,
            "stop" => self::DEFAULT_STOP,
            "parity" => self::DEFAULT_PARITY,
        );
        $this->set_options($options);

        return;
    }
```

Can anyone please help me to sort it out ?

Comment: Can you share your code? The main question should be why dio_fcntl is called from the namespace serial

Comment: @NicoHaase I have edited my question.

Comment: That is no valid PHP code: is this contained in a class? And which is line 131?

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes this whole code is written in a 'Serial' class. I am getting error in   `dio_fcntl($this->serial, F_SETFL, O_SYNC);` and that is line no. 131

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the PHP documentation, it tells you at http://php.net/dio-fcntl that this method is not available on Windows systems.

Comment: Is there any other options are available on windows system ?